# VS for Mac - Using Autolayout for landscape and portrait views

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout, visual-studio-mac

I need help, having spent the day searching through various youtube videos and google etc I've hit that wall!

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and basically, my Logon screen looks good in Portrait but not so in Landscape so I want to show a different view with a redesigned screen especially for Landscape.

Microsoft Forums suggest that I use the `OnSizeAllocated` event to work out the orientation which sounds fine but I just can't work out how you do that.

I have on View Controller which doesn't have any events.  I have one View and that doesn't have any events.  If I try to add the code in manually into the ViewControllers class it doesn't like it.  If I try and add it in `Main.cs` it doesn't like it or `AppDelegate.cs` it doesn't like it.

Designing screens to match the orientation must be like breathing air but for the life of me I just can't work it out and I'm suffocating here!

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to post a bit more about your login screen? how you have constructed it, etc. I would try to do it with AutoLayout if possible but cant tell until you give some more information on your implementation, If you are using a xib/storyboard or code for your view could you post that up?

Comment: can you listen for [UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientationdidchangenotification?language=objc), and then just resize/reposition your views accordingly?

Comment: @Iain Smith - I’ve not really heard of xib - VS for MAC is all storyboard stuff which is built on Xamarin but there are no Xaml files as I’ve seen posts throughout the day where they have used xaml to stack the controls.  (i imagine that last sentence just shows how confused I am).  Anyway i have a background image and then below that the usual username and password controls and below that the logon button.

Comment: @Mark - after dinner I will get my Mac out again and look for that huge notification event.  Where about do I add it please? In the View Controller or elsewhere?

Comment: So if you are using Xamarin.iOS there will be xibs/storyboards or just view code (storyboards are just a collection of xibs with some extra navigation features). If you are using Xamarin.Forms there will be Xaml files in the core project for the layout. So with your Logon screen, there should either be just the code is you have done it programmatically or a storyboard file or a xaml file depending on how you have implemented it. If you add that to your question I should be able to help more.

Comment: Okay...sigh...so I’m using ‘visual studio for Mac’ - thats Literally the name of the environment I’m developing on.  I know it’s based on Xamarin because it needs to run but the code is meant to be done in C# - which I haven’t done any yet.  I have just started a single view project and using the story board added the relevant controls to the View Contoller (or more precisely the View which comes with the View Controller).  I really haven’t done much but figured that it would be best to work out the orientation and do stuff before the app gets complicated.

Comment: Maybe I need to ditch the environment and try the full on Xamarin one...maybe I’m too old...Maybe I need to forget it, after all out of the example apps I’ve looked at they all just automatically resized, I couldn’t see any orientation checks so maybe I’m making too much out of it

Comment: here is a decent explanation for Xamarin, https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationCenter/. however, you could just make your login screen not respond to landscape, and only display as portrait mode

Comment: @Clandestine You're never too old to learn this stuff!!! I have added an answer below which may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the comments, I see you're using `Visual Studio for Mac` (`VS4M`)  as your IDE and you are using the single view template app but are trying to get the view to adapt to landscape and portrait.

If you open your storyboard in `VS4M` you should see something like this:

[image]

I have added some controls (image, username, password, and login button) in the next image just to show how I would create the layout using the iOS designer in `VS4M`

[image]

The key point here is to change to landscape and the press the `Edit Traits` > `Edits apply to Compact Height only`

You can read more about Size Class (Compact/Regular) [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/size-classes/) but this is a good image to get your head around it:

[image]

The Next step is to do the Autolayout for the username, password and login button.

[image]

You'll then have a view like this:
[image]
[image]

I have uploaded this to my GitHub just so you can have a look if you want the link is [here](https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/LandscapePortraitView).

Autolayout is one of the more difficult areas to get your head round in Xamarin.iOS development so I wouldn't be disheartened. Also, this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout) is good for more information on Autolayout with VS4M

If you are not doing in Autolayout but rather in code then if you could post that code, I can take a look and help.

**Update - Adaptive layout**

So to actually change/remove certain constraints for landscape/portrait you have to use the installed property. Here I am changing the image's center constraint to only be installed when in `Any` width and `Regular` height (aka portrait) and then having its left(leading) constraint to be installed when in 'Any' width and 'Compact' height (aka landscape)

[image]

Then to make it nicer I moved the login and password text boxes to the right of that. Firstly I have to make the current Username textbox Vertical Alignment constraint installed only on width `Any` and height `Regular`(portrait) then create a new top constraint to the top of the super view in width `Any` and height `Compact`(landscape).

[image]

Then the last bit is to have the leading(left) Horizontal Spacing constraints of the Username and password textboxes installed only on width `Any` and height `Regular`(portrait) and create two new leading(left) Horizontal Spacing constraints set to the trailing(right) of the image installed on width `Any` and height `Compact`(landscape), Rememeber to make the constant of those constraints 0 (and hit enter on your keyboard to set the value) like so:

[image]

Then the app will look like this:

[image]
[image]

I have updated my [GitHub](https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/LandscapePortraitView) solution with this implementation. Sorry for all the images but I think its best to explain Autolayout with images.

Comment: I woke up this morning and almost cried with happiness.  I really appreciate the time and effort you put in and have been playing around with constraints since.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. If this has solved your issue remember to mark the answer as accepted so other people can see it.

Comment: I guess I just thought that you could have 1 view for portrait where for example the controls were vertically aligned and then another view for Landscape where in our example the logo would be on the far left with the username and password controls in the middle and the logon button on the right.<br/>it would be cool  to click the portrait or Landscape image and instead of Edit Traits button you would have Edit Design Etc

Comment: Yeah, that's possible too but you will have to use the install/uninstall property. I'll update my answer to show how you would do it.

Comment: Hey I have updated the answer with a more adaptive layout when in landscape, let me know if it helps

Comment: It helps - still haven’t quite got there but at least I feel a whole lot better about the situation.  My constraints work definitely needs polishing up!