# How to create responsive UI design in xamarinIOS (Landscape and portrait mode)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm making a app in IOS Xamarin and i want to create separate user interface for both landscape and portrait mode. when the screen changes orientation i want the interface to change too.

[Landscape and portrait mode example i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5j5a.png)

i m using visual studio 2017 for mac. the problem is that i don't know if like in android i can create a secend layout for the landscape mode. if so, can someone explain how, or give a a helpful link where i can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i am familiar with that you can create a responsive design in iOS is to use the concept of [AutoLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout).

But before you start that you should be aware of the [basics of designing in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/introduction?tabs=macos)

In regards to how to handle potrait and landscape mode with AutoLayout you check this [StackOverflow discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412818/vs-for-mac-using-autolayout-for-landscape-and-portrait-views)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different mechanisms for controlling the layout when a view is resized or rotated:

1. **Autosizing**

> The Autosizing inspector in the designer provides a way to set the
>   AutoresizingMask properties. This will let a control be anchored to
>   the edges of their container and/or fix their size. Autosizing works
>   in all versions of iOS.

Refer:[autosizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/layout-options#autosizing)

2. **Auto Layout**

> A feature, introduced in iOS 6 that allows fine-grained control over
>   the relationships of the UI controls. It will allow control of the
>   positions of elements relative to other elements on the design
>   surface.

Refer:[designer-auto-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout)

You can read the documents and download the samples from the links. For complex layout, I recommend you to use **Auto Layout**, for simple layout, I would recommend you to use **Autosizing**.